# How do I mutate a structure I am looping over?

Tags: loops, data-structures, rust, graph-algorithm, borrow-checker

This question is motivated by [this CodinGame puzzle](https://www.codingame.com/training/hard/skynet-revolution-episode-2).

I am implementing a basic pathfinding algorithm using Dijkstra's method. It uses a `boundary` HashMap and a `finished` HashMap to hold pathfinding-related node info. In a particular loop, I find the highest-valued node in `boundary`, remove the node, add the node to `finished`, and add/update the node's neighbors' info in `boundary`.

Attempting to mutate `boundary` while looping over it is making Rust's borrow checker queasy, but the logic of the loop seems sound to me. How do I rewrite it so that the compiler shares my confidence? (Or fix the errors I'm missing, if that's the issue.)

#### Code:

[On Rust Playground here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b71e12ebfd5f2c2ef40b9efbc83803ee&version=stable&backtrace=0)

```
use std::io;
use std::collections::{HashSet, HashMap};
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct NodeInfo {
    nbrs: HashSet<i32>,
    gwlinks: i32,
}

#[derive(PartialEq,PartialOrd)]
struct PFInfo {
    avg: f32,
    cum: i32,
    dist: i32,
    prev: Option<i32>,
}

impl Eq for PFInfo {}

impl Ord for PFInfo {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &PFInfo) -> Ordering {
       match self.partial_cmp(other) {
           Some(ord) => ord,
           None => Ordering::Equal
       }
    }
}

type Graph = HashMap<i32, RefCell<NodeInfo>>;
type PFGraph = HashMap<i32, PFInfo>;

// Find the path that passes the most gateway links per distance traveled,
// starting at a given node. This is meant to simulate the behavior of an
// "agent" which traverses the graph in the puzzle mentioned above.
fn generate_path(si: &i32, graph: &Graph) -> Vec<i32> {
    let n = graph.len();
    let mut boundary = PFGraph::with_capacity(n);
    let mut finished = PFGraph::with_capacity(n);

    boundary.insert( si.clone(),
                     PFInfo {
                         avg: 0.,
                         cum: graph.get(&si).unwrap().borrow().gwlinks,
                         dist: 0,
                         prev: None } );

    // Keep grabbing the key corresponding the highest value until `boundary` is
    // empty
    while let Some( (currid, _) ) = boundary.iter().max_by_key(|x| x.1) {

        // Move the node from `boundary` to `finished`
        let val = boundary.remove(&currid).unwrap();
        finished.insert(currid.clone(), val);

        // Add or update all adjacent nodes that are not in `finished`
        for nbrid in graph.get(&currid).unwrap()
                          .borrow()
                          .nbrs.iter()
                          .filter(|x| !finished.contains_key(x)) {
            let currval = finished.get(&currid).unwrap();
            let prev = Some(currid.clone());
            let dist = currval.dist + 1;
            let cum = currval.cum + graph.get(nbrid).unwrap().borrow().gwlinks;
            let avg = cum as f32 / dist as f32;
            boundary.insert(
                nbrid.clone(),
                PFInfo {
                    avg: avg,
                    cum: cum,
                    dist: dist,
                    prev: prev,
                }
            );
        }
    }

    let mut path = Vec::new();
    let mut currid = finished.iter().max_by_key(|x| x.1).unwrap().0.clone();
    path.push(currid.clone());
    while let Some(previd) = finished.get(&currid).unwrap().prev {
        path.push(previd.clone());
        currid = previd.clone();
    }
    path.reverse();

    path
}



macro_rules! parse_input {
    ($x:expr, $t:ident) => ($x.trim().parse::<$t>().unwrap())
}

#[test]
fn test_generate_path() {
    let mut inputs = "8 13 2
6 2
7 3
6 3
5 3
3 4
7 1
2 0
0 1
0 3
1 3
2 3
7 4
6 5
4
5".lines();

    let header = inputs.next().unwrap().split_whitespace().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let n = parse_input!(header[0], i32); // the total number of nodes in the level, including the gateways
    let l = parse_input!(header[1], i32); // the number of links
    let e = parse_input!(header[2], i32); // the number of exit gateways

    let mut graph = Graph::with_capacity(n as usize);
    for node in 0..n {
        graph.insert(node, RefCell::new(NodeInfo{ nbrs: HashSet::new(), gwlinks: 0 }));
    }
    let graph = graph;

    for _ in 0..l as usize {
        let link = inputs.next().unwrap();
        let nodes = link.split(" ").collect::<Vec<_>>();
        let n1 = parse_input!(nodes[0], i32); // N1 and N2 defines a link between these nodes
        let n2 = parse_input!(nodes[1], i32);

        graph.get(&n1).unwrap().borrow_mut().nbrs.insert(n2);
        graph.get(&n2).unwrap().borrow_mut().nbrs.insert(n1);
    }

    let mut gateways = HashSet::new();
    for _ in 0..e as usize {
        let ei = parse_input!(inputs.next().unwrap(), i32); // the index of a gateway node
        gateways.insert(ei);
    }
    let gateways = gateways;

    for gwid in &gateways {
        for gwnbr in &graph.get(gwid).unwrap().borrow().nbrs {
            (&graph).get(&gwnbr).unwrap().borrow_mut().gwlinks += 1;
        }
    }

    assert_eq!(generate_path(&0, &graph), vec![0, 3]);
}
```

#### Errors:

```
rustc 1.18.0 (03fc9d622 2017-06-06)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `boundary` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> <anon>:53:19
   |
50 |     while let Some( (currid, _) ) = boundary.iter().max_by_key(|x| x.1) {
   |                                     -------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
53 |         let val = boundary.remove(&currid).unwrap();
   |                   ^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
76 |     }
   |     - immutable borrow ends here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `boundary` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> <anon>:66:13
   |
50 |     while let Some( (currid, _) ) = boundary.iter().max_by_key(|x| x.1) {
   |                                     -------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
66 |             boundary.insert(
   |             ^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
76 |     }
   |     - immutable borrow ends here

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Comment: As mentioned by Stargateur, consider making your code reproducible. If you can make it throw the same compilation error in a [Rust Playground](http://play.rust-lang.org/) and add a link to it, the better. Also note that the error you have mentions a binding named `bndry`, now `boundary`.

Comment: In any programming language, you will get unexpected results if you try to modify a structure at the same time as iterating over it.

Comment: Peter Hall there are data structures that provide well-defined/reasonable behavior in spite of modifications during an iteration; arrays would be a trivial example.  It's also possible to provide predictable behavior for more elaborate data structures as well, e.g. if you're willing to have the iterator objects register themselves with the data structure, so that it can update their state as necessary whenever any changes are made to the structure during an iteration.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Array iterators are not robust against shortening, reallocating, or even just reordering the underlying array. It's possible to provide a well-defined and reasonable *interface* to an array that allows in-place mutation during iteration, but it's far from trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue, and it's somewhat generalizable, which is what I was hoping for. The problem was that an implicit reference created in the `while let` statement was living to the end of the loop even though it was only needed on that one line. The borrow begins at `.iter()` and is no longer needed once the referenced value is `clone`d at the end of the expression.

```
while let Some( (currid, _) ) = boundary.iter().max_by_key(|x| x.1).clone() {
    //                                  ^---where borrow begins    ^---where borrow could end

    // Move the node from `boundary` to `finished`
    let val = boundary.remove(&currid).unwrap();
    finished.insert(currid.clone(), val);

    ...

} // <--- where borrow does end
```

The trick was moving the binding of `currid` into the loop. When the value is borrowed in the `while let` statement, the borrow checker apparently thinks the borrow needs to last throughout the loop. If, instead, the implicit borrow is made in a regular `let` binding, the borrow checker is smart enough to realize the borrow can be safely discarded at the end of the line.

```
while !boundary.is_empty() {
    let currid = boundary.iter().max_by_key(|x| x.1).unwrap().0.clone();
    //                   ^---where borrow begins               ^---where borrow ends
    // Move the node from `boundary` to `finished`
    let val = boundary.remove(&currid).unwrap();
    finished.insert(currid.clone(), val);

    ...

}
```

I guess the take away here is that if you need to mutate a structure in a loop that depends on it, put any borrows of the structure inside the loop and keep those borrows as short as possible – for example, by using `clone`.

This might be one of the situations eventually mitigated by the proposed [non-lexical lifetimes](https://github.com/nikomatsakis/nll-rfc/blob/master/0000-nonlexical-lifetimes.md).