# Cannot borrow `self.objects` as mutable more than once at a time

Tags: rust

I have a problem with the following piece of code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct SomeObject {}

enum SomeObjectWrapper<'a> {
    Wrap(&'a SomeObject),
}

struct SomeContainer {
    objects: HashMap<String, SomeObject>,
}

impl SomeContainer {
    fn new() -> SomeContainer {
        SomeContainer {
            objects: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn init(&mut self) -> () {
        let mut collected: Vec<SomeObjectWrapper> = Vec::new();

        for &string in vec!["this", "is", "a", "string"].iter() {
            // search for the artifact in the map
            let obj = self
                .objects
                .entry(string.to_owned())
                .or_insert(SomeObject {});

            let wrap = SomeObjectWrapper::Wrap(obj);
            collected.push(wrap);
        }

        // do something else with collected
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut container = SomeContainer::new();
    container.init();
}
```

Which produces the following compiler error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.objects` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:25:23
   |
25 |               let obj = self
   |  _______________________^
26 | |                 .objects
   | |________________________^ mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop
...
35 |       }
   |       - mutable borrow ends here
```

I have looked at similar posts about this issues and tried adding a new scope inside the loop to drop the mutable reference, or use `&*` to convert to immutable but nothing works.

The only way I can get this code to compile is by commenting out the line:

```
collected.push(wrap);
```

I understand the problem is that the `.or_insert` method returns a mutable borrow which I actually do not need and I should probably stop using the `entry` method, but it is so damn convenient and I won't give up until someone tells me this code cannot be fixed!

Comment: Praise Rust! The compiler is preventing you from writing very problematic code :) You cannot keep references into `self.objects` while at the same time the owning container is mutated. If the hashmap reallocated during `or_insert` all the references in `collected` would get invalidated.

Comment: [Adding entries to a HashMap and getting references to them in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395370/adding-entries-to-a-hashmap-and-getting-references-to-them-in-a-for-loop/48397140) seems to be very similar. Does it answer your question?

Comment: That makes lot of sense actually :) Long live the compiler!

Comment: However, I am not sure what is the rust way of resolving the problem! Should I use a `HashMap<String, Box<SomeObject>>` instead? In that case I will be taking a references to the boxed object and if things gets reallocated my pointer should still be valid isn't it? Spoiler alert: get the same error message! :)